# I created a new windows user but cannot open notepad?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-accounts, notepad

I created a new windows user but I cannot open/start notepad in it.

user accounts

1. Administrator
2. Anilmeena(I created this account)

Problem:

when I login to this 2nd account. and try to open notepad. it does not open it  or display anything?

Administrator can open all accounts without any problem. but The second account cannot?

How did I tried to open the notepad?

1. win+ r-> notepad (type it in box)
2. pressed enter

but nothing happened.

I created a new account test. I can open notepad from this account easily. I think notepad is disabled for account(anilmeena) account.

How can I undo this?

Answer (score 2):

Notepad should open in any user (admin or non-admin).

The Windows Account named Administrator should be disabled, remain  disabled and not used.

Make a new Windows User Account. Make it a member of the Administrators group. Make sure Notepad works.

Now go back and check that Administrator is disabled.  Disable it if it was enabled for some reason.

Delete the account that does not work properly.

To correct possible errors, run DISM and SFC.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run both:

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth    followed by
SFC /SCANNOW

Restart when done and make sure Notepad and all other functions are working properly